# Fourier transform in polar coordinates on a finite range

Tags: fourier-analysis, polar-coordinates

Baddour (2011) derive a general relation (i.e., without assumed symmetries) between the Fourier transform in polar coordinates and the Hankel transform. Specifically, for a function in physical space $f(r, \theta)$ the Fourier transform is

$$
\begin{align}
F(\vec\omega) &= F(\rho, \psi) \\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}F_n(\rho)e^{i n \psi}\label{a}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
F_n(\rho) = 2\pi i^{-n}\mathbb{H}_n \{ f_n(r) \}
$$
and
$$
f_n(r) = {{1}\over{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(r,\theta)e^{-in\theta}d\theta\label{b}\tag{2}
$$

are the Fourier coefficients for $F(\vec\omega)$ and $f(r,\theta)$, respectively (see Section 3.2 of Baddour for details).

Wang et al. (2008) showed that using a Fourier transform on a finite *radial* range required additional k-space terms in the Fourier coefficients (see Section 2.3.2 for details). Admittedly, I did not follow exactly how those terms were derived, and they may be specific to the Helmholtz equation they were solving.

Given all of this, I now wish to attempt to use Equation (1) on a range finite in both $r$ *and* $\theta$. In particular, my physical region is a sequence of concentric annuli each of thickness $2t$ centered on a circle of radius $R$ and discretized into $N$ equal azimuthal bins of size $\theta_m = 2\pi/N$ for $0 \le m \le N$. There are no symmetries in my physical region.

For this problem, my assumption is that Equation (2) would look something like

$$
f_{n,m}(r) = {{1}\over{2\pi}}\int_{\theta_m}^{\theta_{m+1}}f(r,\theta)e^{-in\theta}d\theta\label{c}\tag{3}
$$

However, I hesitate to write this as it breaks the "infinite" transform formulation of Equation (1). At the end of the day, I am interested in plotting the Fourier amplitudes as a function of both $r$ and $\theta$ such that $A_{nk}(r,\theta)$ is the amplitude of the $n$th mode of the radial component and the $k$th mode of the azimuthal component (corresponding to a particular region $\theta_m$).

My questions are thus

1. How do I get started deriving the necessary coefficients for the finite range in $r$? (Even just a reference to a text would be great!)
2. Is it legal to formulate *some* equation that reflects the intention of Equation (3)?

---

## Update

As an interim workaround, I decided to convolve my input with a simple windowing function that would select each finite reach. For now, I am ignoring
the errors introduced by ringing (Gibbs_phenomenon). Using the windowing function

$$
W_{k}(r,\theta;R) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if} \left\vert R - r\right\vert \leq t \text{ and } \theta_{k} \leq \theta \leq \theta_{k+1} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases},
$$

my problem reduces to

$$
g(r,\theta) = f(r,\theta)\ast\ast W_{k}(r,\theta;R)
$$

The Fourier coefficients for the windowing function are just

$$
W_{k}(r;R) = {1 \over {2\pi}} \int_{0}^{2\pi} W_{k}(r,\theta;R)e^{-ik\theta}d\theta
$$

See Section 8 of Baddour (2011) for a proof that the convolution theorem holds for the 2D polar Fourier Transform.

Any thoughts or suggestions for the original problem are still very much welcome!

---

#### References

[Baddour, Natalie](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241069465_Two-Dimensional_Fourier_Transforms_in_Polar_Coordinates). Two-Dimensional Fourier Transforms in Polar Coordinates. Advances in Imaging and Electron Physics 165. 2011.

[Wang, Qing; Ronneberger, Olaf; Burkhardt, Hans](http://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/Publications/2008/WRB08/wa_report01_08.pdf). Fourier Analysis in Polar and Spherical Coordinates. ALBERT-LUDWIGS-UNIVERSITAT FREIBURG INSTITUT FUR INFORMATIK Internal Report. 2008.